# Java VM fatal error in threaded jar application

Tags: java, jvm, fatal-error

I am running threaded code from a jar-file on a linux machine and my code never finishes as I always get a fatal JVM error.

The errors always look similiar but never the same so I do not really know where to look in my code since some have references to it, but some do not.

This is how the short output of the last error looked like:

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: 
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fd468729564, pid=10066, tid=0x00007fd46639d700
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_201-b09) (build 1.8.0_201-b09)
> Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.201-b09 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
> Problematic frame:
> V  [libjvm.so+0x987564]  oopDesc* PSPromotionManager::copy_to_survivor_space(oopDesc*)+0x144

I uploaded the last 4 VM error log files to Filebin: https://filebin.net/3ielrh56qy4cpqv2. 
Hopefully someone can explain what the problem is and give me a solution or hint what to look at.
If you need further information feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance
Paul

Comment: And what does you application looks like? Is it a new developed one? Is it an existing one that used to work? Please provide as much context as possible and add details on what you source code looks like and what has been done / tried so far.

Comment: It's a segmentation fault in the JVM. The first thing to do would be to update your Java version to the latest one of the major one. You have `201-b09` whereas the latest is `251` or thereabouts.

Comment: I will try updating Java now and refer back to you whether I can still reproduce the error.

Comment: A “threaded jar application” is not a useful description. All Java applications use threads and 90% of them are deployed as jar files. Since that’s the only thing you say about what you are doing, you are basically saying nothing at all.